# Issue creating a Xamarin.Forms app on a Windows Server OS

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, windows-server-2016

I wanted to use a windows server OS for *reasons* in my development of a Xamarin.Forms application but am getting an error as it gets to the stage of the creation that it makes the *.UWP project. Does anyone know a way to do this with out using a "client windows OS"? Im using "Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Datacenter" OS. The error is below.

[image]

Comment: why do you want to use a server OS? Why not use a VM with Win10?

Comment: UWP apps are Windows 10 only (at this moment). Thus, you cannot develop that on Windows Server. Just like you cannot develop UWP on Mac. The answer is obvious and no workaround.

Comment: In theory, you can create uwp app on windows server 2016. However, the local debugging is not available on Windows Server. For more you could refer to [Visual Studio 2017 Platform Targeting and Compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs).

Comment: Have you installed [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised I don't need the server OS exactly, I can use a VM on it with windows 10, thanks for the comment magicandre1981.